# How does chrome.storage.local store its data? (2023)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

When using `chrome.storage.local.set()` in a Chrome extension, it seems now in 2023 that the data is being stored in `.log` files under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings\<extension-id>\` with the FULL HISTORY of old data as well as the new one.

**How do you extract only the currently saved data from those .log files?** Is there a system in place?

This question has been asked a dozen times before but none of them are up-to-date with how the storage is located on disk in the latest Chrome versions.

Would love an answer from [Kalman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2278684/kalman), who wrote the storage API :)

> For reference, this is how the file `000003.log` looks like at my end: [image]
> I've been testing by repeatedly removing and adding the same data over time, and almost the full history of addition and deletion is stored in this file. I only want the data that's currently existing as chrome storage, and I need to know how to extract it from this file for backup and reading purposes.

Comment: It still uses the same LevelDB internally. Kalman only wrote the "higher" parts of the API. There are various tools for LevelDB extraction and you can write your own using the library directly.

Comment: @wOxxOm: Thanks :) Can you recommend any tools that are easy to use? I've researched this dozens of times before but never found a single good tool that was easy to use and did the job. Also, do you know why the whole history is also kept? Is that part of the LevelDB spec?

Comment: 1) Last time I checked a few years ago I didn't find such tools. 2) For perfomance reasons. Think of it as a file system where the new data that exceeds a free cluster is written elsewhere. I guess the physical storage gets combined and cleaned up periodically or based on some condition.

Comment: @wOxxOm: I see. My main concern is that the user-generated local data should be persisted *and* easily viewable by the user *without requiring the browser*. I'm wanting to develop an offline extension where the data can be accessed outside of browser. I've seen some [concerns](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=680392&q=indexeddb%20chrome.storage&can=2) about anything other than `chrome.storage` being subject to eviction, so, is `chrome.storage` my only bet at guaranteed data persistence? Thanks for all your helpful knowledge and tips, btw, really appareciate it 

Comment: There's no such storage in Chrome. You'll have to write an external utility and run it via nativeMessaging.

Comment: @wOxxOm: Good news, I did find a super simple [LevelDB CLI](https://github.com/cions/leveldb-cli) that *just worked* with the Chrome ext data, I'm super thrilled :) Thanks for all your help and patience! If you happen to know, I'd love to know if chrome.storage is reliable enough? Are data corruptions common? Will the data be evicted when disk space is sparse? Will writing to the chrome.storage leveldb from an external tool (like the linked cli above) somehow increase the likelihood of data corruption if the leveldb storage is being written to from within chrome *and* from outside? Thanks 

Comment: I don't think it's designed to be particularly fault-resistant because it greatly reduces performance and Chrome has alwaays been about performance, but the fact it's still used in Chrome for 10+ years is a relatively positive indicator, although I see they migrate IndexedDB from LevelDB backend to sqlite citing performance benefits of the latter. I'm not aware of experiments with external modification of the data.

Comment: @wOxxOm: Thanks for your lending your expertise and for your insightful comments. Wish I could've upvoted this as an answer so as to you give you something back, but know that it is greatly appreciated 